# wait() and notify() method in java

Tags: java

i have seen so many examples in which we called `wait()` and `notify()` method directly like below.

```
class ThreadB extends Thread{
    int total;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
            for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
                total += i;
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

but in the object class, method signature of notify is defined as

```
public final void notify()
```

Can someone please explain how we can call these method directly without using an object as these methods are not defined as static.

Comment: You *do* have an object; it's `this`.

Comment: If you read first chapter in java... you will realise all classes extend Object class. So all methods are inherited of Object class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method invocation expression of the form `MethodName ( [ArgumentList] )` invokes the method of the current class. If the method is not static, it is invoked on the current object, i.e. the object `this` points to. That is, the method invocation expression `notify()` is just a shorthand for writing `this.notify()`.

The implementation of `notify()` can then query its `this` to find out which object's waiting threads should be notified.

Answer (score 1):

In java, each class extends class Object directly or indirectly. Thats why methods that are defined in class Object - for example- wait(), notify(), equals(), hashcode() etc are available to use.

check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) :

and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)

Answer (score 0):

These methods are the part of Object class(Superclass of every class), and hence these methods are getting inherited(implicitly) in all the classes that you write.

Coming to static part, calling these methods does not need them to be static as they are the part of your class, and hence when you say wait(), you actually mean its getting called on the correct object in hand.